# ibm video player embed code not responding to autoplay code

Tags: video, iframe, html5-video, media-player, autoplay

Hi I am trying to get this html code to autoplay the video however it doesn't work.

This is the code I used:

```
<div  id="Container"  style="padding-bottom:56.25%; position:relative; display:block; width: 100%"
><iframe id="UstreamIframe" src="https://video.ibm.com/embed/recorded/131906526?html5ui=1&autoplay=true"
    width="100%" height="100%"
    style="position:absolute; top:0; left: 0"
    allowfullscreen
    webkitallowfullscreen
    frameborder="0"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
  ></iframe>
</div>
```

I have tried various ways of adjusting the URL however each time, I get the exact same results. Any help would be most appreciated.